# Why is this function declared twice? Where is the callback function declared?

Tags: javascript

http://codepen.io/Lewitje/pen/GjqbbA

Looking at this and trying to figure out what is happening is discouraging me. I've been doing a javascript deep dive lately and I understand objects, constructors, prototypes etc. and on css end I know animation with keyframes, canvas, coordinates etc yet looking at this I know maybe 40-50% of the javascript that is written there.

1) I know that a class and constructor is declared (this is relatively new to javascript?)

2) jQuery .each method is used to attach labels A1, A2 etc. with setupLabels()

3) A variety of different functions to display the number punched in on the dial, move the arm, move the can etc.

Now this is where it gets confusing for me:

```
setPosition(x, y, callback){
    $('.hand').on('transitionend', ()=>{

        $('.hand').off('transitionend');

        setTimeout(function(){
            callback();
        }, 500);

    });

    this.calculateVelocity(x, y, (velX, velY)=>{
        $('.arm').css({
            'top': (y + 35) + 'px',
            'transition-duration': velY + 's'
        });

        $('.hand').css({
            'left': (x + 5) + 'px',
            'transition-duration': velX + 's',
            'transition-delay': velY + 's'
        });
    });
}

calculateVelocity(x, y, callback){
    var currentX = $('.hand')[0].offsetLeft;
    var currentY = $('.arm')[0].offsetTop;

    var velX = Math.ceil((Math.max(currentX, x) - Math.min(currentX, x)) / 70);
    var velY = Math.ceil((Math.max(currentY, y) - Math.min(currentY, y)) / 70);

    callback(velX, velY);
}
}
```

I'm guessing the this.calculateVelocity is infact, calling the function and the what comes after => is defining the callback function?

If that is the case how does the callback in setPosition work as it hasn't been defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript starts by compiling a list of all the function names before it runs, so `calculateVelocity` **has** been defined. Additionally, you are correct, `(velX, velY) => {}` is the callback, and the function is being called. It's in the new [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) format.

Both of the following are identical:

```
this.calculateVelocity(x, y, (velX, velY) => {
    ...
});

this.calculateVelocity(x, y, function(velX, velY) {
    ...
});
```

Inside `setPosition`, `this` refers to the global object. In this case, `calculateVelocity` is a function on the global object, and so it can be called via `this.calculateVelocity`.

I should also note that the source JavaScript in the linked Codepen is actually TypeScript/ES7.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. This new Class thing is confusing me, normally we'd declare a method by using function and then call it separately but in this case function prefix is not even used once?

Comment: @kshatriiya can you be more specific?

Comment: @JsoephGarrone, in the code block above, setPosition(x, y, callback) {} 

is the method declaration. I can tell this as the method was called in getPosition() method in the .js file. However normally, if we want to define a method we would do function setPosition(x, y, callback) {} ?

Comment: @kshatriiya not in this case because typescript does away with the need to use `function` if its inside a class declaration, which it is.